# Help evaluating summation.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to evaluate:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{10}^{i/n}}{n}$$

My thought is convert it to convert it to an integral:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{10}^{i/n}}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{10}^{i/n} \times \frac{1}{n} $$

Which means:

$$ \frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{1}{n} $$

$$ b - a = 1 $$

Therefore we can say the integral evaluates from **0 and 1 (not sure about this)**:

$$ \int_0^1{10^{x} dx}$$

And using U-substitution I get:

$$ \frac{1}{ln(10)} \times e^{ln(10)} - \frac{1}{ln(10)} $$

$$ \frac{9}{ln(10)} $$

Did I do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should recognize this as a Riemann sum, with value

$$\int_0^1 dx \, 10^x  = \int_0^1 dx \, e^{\log{10} x}=\frac1{\log{10}} (e^{\log{10}}-1)= \frac{9}{\log{10}}$$